# I am getting a TypeError for Langchain imports on CoLab. I'm relatively new to coding and am not sure what it means

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, typeerror, langchain

**This is the error:
**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-f7039c6de9d7> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
      2 from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
----> 3 from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
      4 from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
      5 

21 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py in __subclasscheck__(self, cls)
   1156             return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)
   1157         if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
-> 1158             return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
   1159         return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
   1160 

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

**This is the code I'm getting the error for:
**

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain


import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]="---"

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0,model_name="chat-gpt")
```

I tried using the "newer" typing version of importing functions from langchain, but it didn't work. I'm getting the same error for all langchain imports, not just the code pasted here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Consider your openai key no longer usable as you've mistakenly posted it.  Please regenerate your open AI key.  Next time, don't include any credentials in your post.